# PHP regex match optional content reserving array position

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse some Apache error logs

these are the example string I'm trying to match

```
[Mon May 19 15:56:43 2014] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to 111.111.111.111:3000 (111.111.111.111) from 111.111.111.111 ()
```

and

```
[Mon May 19 15:58:00 2014] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: prefetch request body failed to 111.111.111.111:3000 (111.111.111.111) from 111.111.111.111 ()
```

and

```
[Mon May 19 23:14:56 2014] [error] (70014)End of file found: proxy: prefetch request body failed to 111.111.111.111:3000 (111.111.111.111) from 111.111.111.111 ()
```

I'm using this regular expression

```
^\[([^\]]+)\] \[([^\]]+)\] \(?([0-9]+)?\)?([a-zA-Z,\ ,\:]+)([0-9,\.\:]+) \(([0-9,\.]+)\) from ([0-9,\.]+) \(\)
```

this bit

```
\(?([0-9]+)?\)?
```

is to make (70007) or (70014) optional.

1. [1-25]  `Thu Apr 10 18:35:49 2014`
2. [28-33] `error`
3. [36-41] `70007`
4. [42-116]    `The timeout specified has expired: proxy: prefetch request body failed to`
5. [116-135]   `111.111.111.111:3100`
6. [137-151]   `111.111.111.111`
7. [158-172]   `111.111.111.111`

this is the output when it finds (70007) or (70014) if it doesn't find it will output this

1. [1-25]  `Mon Jul 07 17:07:04 2014`
2. [28-33] `error`
3. [35-70] `proxy: pass request body failed to`
4. [70-89] `111.111.111.111:3000`
5. [91-105]    `111.111.111.111`
6. [112-125]   `111.111.111.111`

this going into an array I wanted to have the array position opened but empty or with 0 like this

```
1.  [1-25]  `Mon Jul 07 17:07:04 2014`
2.  [28-33] `error`
4.  [36-41] ``
5.  [35-70] `proxy: pass request body failed to `
5.  [70-89] `111.111.111.111:3000`
6.  [91-105]    `111.111.111.111`
7.  [112-125]   `111.111.111.111`
```

Answer

The solution was

```
\(?([0-9|\ ]+)?\)?
```

instead of

```
\(?([0-9]+)?\)?
```

since the ( ) and the numbers were optional by the ? I used an or | to choose numbers or exact match to a white space and it now returns

```
1.  [1-25]  `Mon May 19 15:56:43 2014`
2.  [28-33] `error`
4.  [35-70] `proxy: pass request body failed to `
5.  [70-90] `111.111.111.111:3000`
6.  [92-107]    `111.111.111.111`
7.  [114-129]   `111.111.111.111`
```

as you can see it skips a position goes from 2 to 4 unless it has (00000) in there.
hope this helps anyone else.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please accept one and close the question so other SO users are not trying to work on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression to achieve your desired output.

```
preg_match('~\[([^]]+)\]             # Match open/close brackets and capture date
              \s+                    # Match any white-space character
              \[([^]]+)\]            # Match open/close brackets and capture "error"
              \s+                    # Match any white-space character
              (?:\(([^)]+)\))?       # Match and capture optional group
              (\D+)                  # Match and capture any character not a digit
              \s+                    # Match any white-space character
              ([\d:.]+)              # Match and capture first set of digits
              \s+                    # Match any white-space character
              \(([^)]+)\)            # Match and capture digits inside parentheses
              \D+                    # Match any character thats not a digit
              ([\d.]+)               # Match and capture last set of digits
            ~x', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fV9eJ9/2)

Comment: @flynn This post should be the accepted one. It is, as zx81 said, *epic*, and will return the optional number *without* the enclosing parenthesis (in contrast to my answer). +1 hwnd

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks, appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Done, yes and the explanation helped allot, the other answer just came first. Thank you so much for you time and patience i was trying them on the regex101 where you had you demo. :)